# windows xp SP3 + active directory 2008R2+ local printer connected to this computer disabled

Tags: active-directory, printer, permissions

i have added some windows xp SP3 to a domain controller (windows 2008R2). The issue comes when i try to add a local printer (usb or primoPDF printer) to a limited user account. When i try to install primoPDF, when it tries to install the printer, gives me an error (privileges). When i try to add it manually (control panel->printers), the option " local printer connected to this computer" is disabled, so i deduce that the user doesn't have rights to  install local printers.

i researched on internet, and i came along with some solutions, but they dont work:

1. giving the active directory (from now on, AD) user, local admin privileges (restricted groups). Still disabled. (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2S8pkW1fZxs)
2. adding the printer with the AD Administrator account. Still disabled.
3. adding the printer with the local Administrator account. Still disabled.
4. applying a GPO about disabling the option "Disable the addition of printers" (http://www.ehow.com/how_6857841_allow-user-add-local-printer.html). Still disabled.

Does anybody know some kind of solution for this issue? my main aim is to install a PDF printer, but is not possible since i included the machines to the AD 2008 R2.

thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If you can't install with the Local Admin account then something is very wrong. Remove **all** group policies applied to that machine and go from there.

Comment: What happens when you try install a standard printer for a local TCPIP port using a builtin driver, while using the local Administrator account?

Comment: @Dan, thanks for your answer. I deleted all GPOs, and got rid of the issue. Later i tested all GPOs and found the one that created the failure. i don't know exactly the policy in particular. Thanks for your help again.